# sed - adding a line when it doesn't exist

Tags: sed

I have a file `formsweb.cfg` which might look a little like this

```
# These match variables (e.g. %form%) in the baseHTML file. Their values
# may be overridden by specifying them in the URL query string
# (e.g. "http://myhost.example.com/forms/frmservlet?form=myform&width=700")
# or by overriding them in a specific, named configuration (see below)
[default]
# Default Oracle Forms values:
#baseHTML=base.htm
#baseHTMLjpi=basejpi.htm
width=1366
height=734

[sepwin]
separateFrame=True
lookandfeel=Generic

[debug]
serverURL=/forms/lservlet/debug
```

This file is missing the key-value `clientDPI=96` which should be located in the `[default]` section of this file.

On 100+ sites, some of the files might have clientDPI set, others might not.

**I want to add the value to files which do not currently have it.**

This is the `sed` script that I wrote. Is there a *"better"* way to do it?

```
sed -n '/\[default\]/,/^\[/ {
  /^clientDPI/q1
}' formsweb.cfg &&

sed '/\[default\]/,/^\[/ {
 /^\[default\]/ {
   a\
clientDPI=96
 }
}' -i.bak.${RANDOM} formsweb.cfg
```

It checks if clientDPI exists between [default] and the next `[` character. If it does it quits with `1`, otherwise, it goes to the next `sed` line, which does the insert.

GNU sed version 4.1.5

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a sed script, either as you have done or using branches to only execute sed once, but as you ask for a better way, I would use a dedicated more general script, easier to adapt. After all, tomorrow you will maybe want to change "lookandfeel" to "newgeneric", or "serverURL" to "/forms/lservlet/debugmore". For example:

- [Crudini](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programs/crudini/)
- [perl module Config::IniFiles](http://metacpan.org/pod/Config%3A%3AIniFiles)
- [roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274955/how-to-modify-the-ini-file-in-perl)